# Django Select Post Request(return id, not value)

Tags: python, django, select, post, render

I have code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="engine" name="engine">
  {% for engine in engines %}
    <option name="{{engine.id}}">{{engine.name}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

print request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {u'engine': [u'test1'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'9rICLe2X1m0KBnxLjY7V2gYoeV5Dd3m6']}>
```

I want get id in "engine"(not value). How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line `<option name="{{engine.id}}">{{engine.name}}</option>` to:

```
<option value="{{engine.id}}">{{engine.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> I want get id in "engine"(not value)

You mean in your view? Isn't that simply

```
request.POST['engine']
```